Rails Routing - 'api/v1/sessions' is not a supported controller name
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:create, :show, :index]

      post '/login', to: 'sessions:#create'
      delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
      get '/logged_in', to: 'sessions#is_logged_in?'

      # resources :sessions
    end
  end
end


I'm not sure what's wrong with my routes. I even tried changing post '/login' to post '/api/v1/login' but that didn't work either. When I commented out the above routed and uncommented resources :sessions, everything worked fine. Can someone please guide me on the solution?

'sessions#create'

Do you have app/controllers/api/v1/SessionsController.rb?

app/controllers/api/v1/sessions_controller.rb is correct

what does not work? do you have controllers? do you have tests?

Yeah like @Alex mentioned there is a typo in your code with an unnecessary colon

Thanks to @Alex for pointing out that the issue was just a typo at sessions:#create. There was an unnecessary : that needed to be removed, and it's working!
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:create, :show, :index]

      post '/login', to: 'sessions:#create'
      delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
      get '/logged_in', to: 'sessions#is_logged_in?'

      # resources :sessions
    end
  end
end

